# 2x rs232 communication, single wirelss connection, also rs232 to control load cell perameters

Tags: amplifier, wifi, rs232, load-cell, plc

I am struggling to find any information on the ability to have 2 rs232 connections with 1 wifi connection.

I have found this wireless chip, which supports, five Ethernet ports, two serial ports:
http://www.hlktech.net/product_detail.php?ProId=62

But my question is whether such a chip or similiar would be able to wirelessly transmit and receive 2 rs232 connections through wifi.

I will be based in china, to make this project soon, and this is another information site, but its chinese:
world.taobao.com/item/524654936858.htm?fromSite=main&spm=a312a.7700824.w4002-15157484274.47.DIEyhj

I am trying to create a rs232 COMS PLC, which also has load cells connected.
I want to use a windows tablet to transmit a rs232 command to the PLC, and also send and receive load cell parameters and readings from another rs232 connections hook up to a load cell amplifier and to the load cells.
But all of this through 1 wifi connection.

Is this possible to do?
I do want to steer away from a dedicated CPU to interpret signals and send them vai wifi, i am looking for the simplest method to send and receive rs232 vai wifi.
But if this is the only method i may have to do so.

i have seen these:
http://www.usconverters.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=70&products_id=404
But i want to create a custom PCB which has a load cell amplifer, wireless rs232 connections, and customized port to connect load cells and PLCs.
All on 1 board.

Just want to make sure 2x rs232 connections is possible first before i pursue something like this.

Another question is:
i am looking for a load cell amplifier which can have its parameters changed by a rs232 connection to suit any load cell type, such as a change in excitation from 8v to 5v, this way the amplifier can suit any load bar, just by adjusting a setting though rs232.
Preferably a open source amplifer, so that i can use some of its design in my custom design.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at NMEA 0183 standard or ESP8266. you do realize you have to Mux/demux with addressable ports.

Comment: The first question you will have to ask yourself is *how will you send / receive UART data over WiFi?* The two systems are so vastly different you will have to have some idea of how you intend to perform the data transfers. Really for that you want some form of MCU to interface to the WiFi and link it to internal UARTs in some way.

Comment: It sounds like you want an off-the-shelf chip that does it all for you. I doubt you'll find one that does exactly what you want. But making it yourself with an MCU is not a huge task, especially if you use a simple to use system like Arduino for programming.

Comment: The NMEA 0183 standard uses a simple ASCII, serial communications protocol that defines how data are transmitted in a "sentence" from one "talker" to multiple "listeners" at a time. Through the use of intermediate expanders, a talker can have a unidirectional conversation with a nearly unlimited number of listeners, and using multiplexers, multiple sensors can talk to a single computer port.

Comment: I may have found something which will help: world.taobao.com/item/533173092158.htm?fromSite=main&spm=a312a.7700824.w4002-15476456498.26.XbJHwD